# Replace some character in string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string of 8 characters '00001111' I want to replace some specific index value. For example if I check `stringName[2]=='0'` and replce it
using `stringName.replace(2,2,"1")` then it replaces but one character is missed at the end

```
if (xyz[3]=='0')
{
    xyz.replace(3,3,"1");
}
else
{
    xyz.replace(3, 3, "0");
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: You make it too complicated. Just simply `stringName[2] = '1';`

Comment: don't put images of code or output. Paste the text here

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: For code, yes, I agree. But what's wrong with images of output?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Answers go down there, bud ↓↓↓↓

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it is often useful to quote parts of the output in answers. Parts of an image cannot be simply copy pasted, so images create unnecessary work for people who write answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't encourage answering turds please, that's not useful from LTV. Rather point to documentation for giving an example (I can't believe I'm actually saying this).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [Note](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553065/replace-some-character-in-string?noredirect=1#comment64498018_38553065)

Comment: I don't particularly like images for output when the output is text. Although I suspect the reason for the image is most new people don't know how to copy and paste with a command window.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why did you link to the comment I'd just replied to? o.O

Answer (score 2):

The problem is misuse of the replace method, the first parameter is index of the start for replace, the second is **length**, and the third is the string that should be inserted. hence saying replace(2,2,"0") means replace the two chars that start at index 2 with "0" (a string of one char), that is why you have chars disappearing.

the solution is as people said, string[index_you_want_to_replace] = 'some_char'.