# C++ virtual class from base pointer?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Criminal {
public:
    virtual void getType() = 0;
    virtual void getCrime() { cout << "Unknown" << endl; }
};

class Thug : public Criminal {
public:
    void getType() { cout << "Thugging" << endl; }
    void getCrime() { cout << "Gangsterism" << endl; }
};

class Tupac : public Thug {
public:
    void getType() { cout << "Rapper" << endl; }
    void getCrime() {
        cout << "Being the best rapper to ever live" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Criminal* tupac = new Tupac();
    Criminal* thug = new Thug();
    Thug* poser = new Tupac(); // Thug has no virtual function
    //Criminal shouldNotCompile;

    tupac->getType();       
    tupac->getCrime();      

    thug->getType();        
    thug->getCrime();       

    poser->getType();       // I intend to call Thug::getType()
    poser->getCrime();      // I intend to call Thug::getCrime()

    delete tupac;
    delete thug;
    delete poser;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Rapper
Being the best rapper to ever live
Thugging
Gangsterism
Rapper
Being the best rapper to ever live
```

But I intend the poser calls from the Thug pointer to print "Thugging" and "Gangsterism."

How can I do this? I expected my code to work as is, because the "Thug" functions are not virtual, so shouldn't anything called from a Thug* pointer call the Thug functions?

Why doesn't my code work the way I intended it to? Where is my confusion?

What is an easy way to get my intended behavior?

Comment: I'm confused. You've created two instances of `Tupac` - why do you expect them to behave differently? The whole point of virtual member function is that the override in the most-derived class is called.

Comment: Also, `delete tupac;` and the other two `delete` calls exhibit undefined behavior, as `Criminal`'s destructor is non-virtual.

Comment: *"the "Thug" functions are not virtual"* False. Overrides of virtual functions are themselves virtual, though `virtual` keyword can be omitted. `Thug::getType()` and `Thug::getCrime()` are in fact virtual member functions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, now it makes sense why it doesnt work.  But a question regarding `delete tupac` Wouldnt it just call the animal destructor and then free the allocated memory?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Why not just write an answer?

Comment: Animal destructor? What animal destructor?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the criminal destructor.  Wouldn't `delete tupac` call the criminal destructor?

Comment: @Barry Just as soon as [y'all figure out what should or shouldn't be an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553065/replace-some-character-in-string?noredirect=1#comment64498018_38553065). I must admit I still don't grasp the proper etiquette on SO. I'm a simple newsgroups dweller, the existence of two different ways to, let's say, speak out frightens and confuses me. Sadly, SO effectively destroyed my natural habitat.

Comment: Deleting an instance of derived class via a pointer to base class lacking a virtual destructor exhibits undefined behavior. Calling the base class destructor is indeed one possible manifestation of undefined behaivor. [Making demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtual`-ness of member functions is inherited. You may not have declared `Thug::getType()` to be `virtual`, but it still is because `Criminal::getType()` is. Invoking `getType()` on any type whose object inherits from `Criminal` will still go through virtual dispatch. Unless, you explicitly specify *which* `getType()` you want:

```
poser->getType(); // virtual dispatch, ends up invoking Tupac::getType()
poser->Thug::getType(); // explicitly call Thug::getType(), no dispatch
```

---

These calls:

```
delete tupac;
delete thug;
delete poser;
```

are dangerous due to `Criminal`'s destructor not being `virtual`. You're not actually freeing all the memory or destroying all the members.

Comment: Right, wouldnt deleting tupac call the Criminal destructor and then free the  memory allocated for tupac?

Comment: @Jason It would call the `Criminal` destructor, yes. But it wouldn't call the `Thug` or `Tupac` destructors.

Comment: @Jason no, the destructor is not virtual, so when you delete a criminal* pointer, it invokes the criminal destructor.

Comment: Ah okay, but what would happen to the memory allocated by new for tupac? Would it never get deallocated?

Comment: @Jason It's undefined behavior. All bets are off at that point.